# Can the /OE pin of a buffer be left floating?

Tags: digital-logic, buffer

Here is a [buffer](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC74VHC1GT125-D.PDF) from OnSemi which has an /OE pin that should be tied high for high impedance mode. For all active modes the pin value is stated as low. Would my buffer still work if I were to leave this pin unconnected or do I explicitly need to ground it?

Comment: Ground it via a 1K (10K or 100K if it's CMOS) resistor. Then you can pull it high to test the high impedance mode.

Comment: You can leave it floating if you want a randomly interesting life. If not, tie it somewhere that allows you to DESIGN what is state will be using datasheet parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /OE pin is an input just like a regular input such as INA on the device.

The device's data sheet says that the maximum input leakage current is up to +/- 1 uA. This means that it may drag down (to 0V) the unconnected input in trying to draw 1 uA from an open circuit OR it may drag up the input (to Vcc).

This means you cannot leave it floating because you CANNOT know what state it will move to.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if there is no explicit mentioning in the data sheet that a logic pin is internally pulled up/down, you have to provide a defined logic level. 
If you leave it floating, it may appear low, but it may also be susceptible to noise.

Answer (score 2):

This is a CMOS logic device so all inputs must be tied to a legitimate logic level. Either drive it from another CMOS device's output, or connect it to Vcc or Gnd.

If you leave a CMOS logic input floating, that input will "drift" into the no-man's land between a legitimate logic-low voltage and a legitimate logic-high, which will cause the output PMOS-NMOS pair to enter the linear zone of operation. In the linear zone both transistors will partially turn on, causing a large current to flow between Vcc and Gnd within the device. When this happens the device will misbehave in several ways.